# Hash verses encryption for email confirmation

Tags: php, email, security, encryption, hash

Our website has for a long time used an email confirmation procedure to confirm the email address of a new member. That function uses a hash function described further below. Now we are upgrading our unsubscribe feature with a more robust process, and as part of that process a similar confirmation mechanism is being proposed. (The unsubscribe procedure is a separate procedure from the email confirmation procedure.)

My question is in looking at the two different mechanisms, hash-based verses encryption-based, are we introducing any vulnerabilities?

In my opinion the newly proposed encryption-based mechanism is better in several ways, and is even stronger than the legacy hash-based mechanism.

Here are the details:

The hash-based mechanism inserts into an email sent to the user a link with a query string like the following:

```
https://www.ourdomain.com/ourpage.php?hash=b7e64c61be853daa1d31a2b879634d09&email=mailbox%40ourdomain.com
```

The hash is a simple hash of the email address, which is included in the query string in plain text. The hash function is as follows:

```
md5('mailbox@ourdomain.com' . HASH_PADDING);
```

When the user clicks on that link, the following happens during the creation of the page:

1. The hash is computed from the plain text email (which of course first has the %40 rendered back to the @ character).
2. The hash is confirmed to match the hash in the email.
3. The hash is used to lookup the account, because that hash was stored in the account records.

We prefer the proposed encryption-based mechanism, which we think is simpler and yet stronger.

Here is the proposed encryption-based mechanism:

The encryption-based mechanism inserts into an email sent to the user a link with a query string like the following:

```
https://www.ourdomain.com/ourpage.php?code=eStYWlBPNVkvL1ljSk1yWHFkNkkvejFGUzcwSTFON1ZFU0NZdzE2dGRoMD0=
```

The code is an encrypted version of the email address with an initialization vector. I don't think it is important to give the details of the encryption beyond to note that the openssl_encrypt library is used, along with base64 encoding.

When the user clicks on that link, the following happens during the creation of the page:

1. The code is decrypted to obtain the email address.
2. The email address is used to lookup the account.

The benefits of the encryption-based method are the following:

1. No plain text email address is transmitted.
2. No need to store a hash code in the database.
3. Encryption method is far stronger than the hash method.

Drawbacks of encryption-based method:

1. The computation of the cipher text takes more resources. However this is academic and I am only pointing it out to avoid the need for comments on this aspect.

Also, please note that the security policy does not involve any high security needs. All we are doing is confirming the email address of a member.

To restate the question: are we introducing any vulnerabilities with the proposed encryption-based method?

Comment: If you're storing the hash in the database, then there's no need to include the plain text email in the link. Just look up the user record based on the hash.

Comment: Also note that with the hash method, you can remove the hash from the user record after it's been used. This prevents an email from being activated more than once and gives you a mechanism to determine which emails have been activated. With the encryption method, you don't get either of those things. (You don't get them innately, I mean. You can obviously still make edits to the user record appropriately.)

Comment: Either method, it does not matter. Upon signup you should store a value, does not need to be cryptographically secure as its simply a validation token that the email supplied for confirmation was the one entered upon signup, it adds an additional check which otherwise would return true if no token was used, and then can be brute forced. Upon successfully verifying you should remove the token.

Comment: Also, don't create the hash from the email address, create it from some `random_bytes()`.

Comment: However in future if you ever decide to change the key , then the old links to un-subscribe will not work or you will have to continue to maintain the old key as well . As such there is not vulnerability with the change.

Comment: Great comments so far!

Comment: `var_dump(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)));` >> `string(32) "673defad41830ac8e7803cfe6ad72857"` and now it's just a straight lookup with no hash computation or encryption or data leaks.

Comment: This should be asked on security.stackexchange.com as it doesn't contain any programming (most experts are lingering there as well)

Comment: Note that if you would still go for the encryption method - probably not recommended anymore - that you should also take padding oracle attacks into account. Changes of the ciphertext may also lead into different but valid email addresses. Basically you would be required to use authenticated encryption to make it secure.

Comment: We have modified our approach. In effect, one or more of the comments above could now be accepted as the answer. The application of the new approach is in the area of "unsubscribe" requests; not directly the email confirmation issue; however the approach could be retrofitted to the email confirmation function as well. There is a separate well-known issue, the so-called "silent unsubscribe" wherein the email gets forwarded and the recipient of the forwarded email unsubscribes the original recipient. Continued ....

Comment: ... (continued). To deal with that issue in the "unsubscribe" application, we have added the requirement that the user must enter the email address. So there is no longer the need to provide the encrypted email address, and rather strong hash is now used.

Answer (score 0):

> The hash is a simple hash of the email address, which is included in the query string in plain text. The hash function is as follows:
>
> ```
> md5('mailbox@ourdomain.com' . HASH_PADDING);
> ```

Haave you ever heard of [length extension attacks](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks)? If you had prepended the padding instead of appending it, you'd be outright vulnerable to textbook LEAs.

As it stands, MD5 is a very poor choice for a hash function. You want SHA256. If you're combining it with a secret key, you want HMAC-SHA256.

```
hash_hmac('sha256', 'mailbox@ourdomain.com', HASH_PADDING);
```

> I don't think it is important to give the details of the encryption beyond to note that the openssl_encrypt library is used, along with base64 encoding.

You think wrong! Read up on [using encryption and authentication securely](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly). If you're using AES-256-CBC, for example, an attacker can use a [padding oracle attack](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/) to decrypt email addresses without knowing the key, thereby defeating the encryption.

> To restate the question: are we introducing any vulnerabilities with the proposed encryption-based method?

Possibly. See above.

Comment: The original post is from quite a ways back, and our algorithm has changed several times since then. We are now using the following: base64_encode(password_hash($string, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)), which I believe avoids all of your issues.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `password_hash()` is a poor fit for this.

Comment: Why is it a poor fit?

Comment: Because password hashing functions were meant for passwords (low-entropy human-memorizable inputs). It's a waste of CPU resources. You're better off using `sodium_crypto_auth()` and `sodium_crypto_auth_verify()` here.

Comment: The CPU resources is not an issue due to low usage. Any other factors relevant?

Comment: It's not about it being "an issue", it's about using the right tool for the job. That's why I said "poor fit" not "vulnerability" :P